# JSON parsing in Cocoa only displaying first 20 entries

Tags: xcode, json, macos, cocoa, parsing

**Update 22nd April:**

*Problem solved: Turned out that the API required OAUTH to work... which explained why it would load correctly in the browser (I was already signed in) and not in other applications such as the JSON validator or my own App.*

I'm trying to write a class which will fetch and parse a JSON file in Xcode 4.3.2 on Lion. I've only been coding for a few weeks so sorry if this is a bit of a stupid question! The code seems to work fine except for the fact that only the first 20 entries in the JSON file show up (there should be 200). Any idea why this might be?

```
   - (void) initJSON
{
NSString *urlstri = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://api.t.sina.com.cn/statuses/followers.json?source=?????&count=200&screen_name=%@", userName];
NSURL *newURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlstri];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:newURL];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
       [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:NO];
                   }
       ];}
- (void) fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
//parse out the json data
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1

                      options:kNilOptions 
                      error:&error];


NSArray* newestFollower = [json objectForKey:@"users"]; //2
fnumber = 0;
mnumber = 0;

int arraySize = [newestFollower count];
NSLog(@"%i",arraySize);

for (i=0; i<arraySize; ++i) {
    NSDictionary* userProfile = [newestFollower objectAtIndex: i];
    NSString* userGender = [userProfile objectForKey:@"gender"];
    //NSLog(@"%@", userGender);
    if([userGender isEqualToString:@"m"]){
        //NSLog (@"man");
        ++mnumber;
    }
    if([userGender isEqualToString:@"f"]){
        //NSLog(@"notman");
        ++fnumber;}
}

mOutput = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(mnumber)];
fObj = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", fnumber];
mObj = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", mnumber];
NSLog (@"Boys:%@", mObj);
NSLog (@"Girls:%@", fObj);
```

Comment: Have you tried copying your `urlStri` and pasting into a browser to verify that the server is indeed returning 200 items like you expect?  When you NSLog the `arraySize` in your code is it 20 or 200?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. When I copy the URL into the browser it returns all 200 items, yet the arraySize is only 20. If I NSLog the json NSDictionary I also get only 20 items..

Comment: Is your JSON format valid? Please validate it in [jsonlint.org](http://jsonlint.org) and report

Comment: I've entered the URL into jsonlint.org and it comes out as valid... though it only returns 20 values too!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but you could try requesting your data asynchronously using an `NSURLConnection` instead of the synchronous `NSData` `dataWithContentsofURL` method.

It would look something like this:

```
- (void) initJSON
{
    NSString *urlstri = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://api.t.sina.com.cn/statuses/followers.json?source=??????&count=200&screen_name=%@", userName];
    NSURL *newURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlstri];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:newURL];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:NO];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I added that code in and It kept on asking for a "];" to be added before the last curly bracket. I managed to get it to give me a response (albeit still with an error message in the log) by adding in this code, essentially adding in what it asked for and removing the error definition (I've added the changed code to the question above). But even with doing that there's still only 20 results...

Comment: Oops, yes, I was missing a close bracket.

Answer (score 0):

There could be an issue with the encoding. Some characters might give problems when parsing (I've encountered this in the past with a HTMLParser library).

First you could try setting a different encoder. If this won't work, perhaps replace problematic chars from the content string. In a past project I used the following due to issues with a HTML parser:

```
NSString *contents = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];

// for parsing this weird char has te be removed, else will only parse partially ...
contents = [contents stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Ó" withString:@"O"]; 

data = [contents dataUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
```

Sadly I couldn't figure out a cleaner solution.

You should try to figure out if your content got some special chars that can't be parsed correctly and "clean" the content from these special chars before parsing.

P.S.: from Apple's documentation on the JSON serializer

> The data must be in one of the 5 supported encodings listed in the JSON specification: UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-32BE. The data may or may not have a BOM. The most efficient encoding to use for parsing is UTF-8, so if you have a choice in encoding the data passed to this method, use UTF-8.

Comment: Just changed the encoding as you suggested and still no difference!

Comment: Don't change it exactly to what I have. Just create a NSString of the responseData and log it. Figure out if the string contains a char that's problematic when parsing.